# Error: "Must declare the scalar variable" for insert statements in multiple database

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, scope

I created a SQL script to add an entry in different database. However, when I run the script through SQL Server Management Studio.

```
declare @address varchar(50)
set @address = 'Hope'

use DB1
go

insert into Address
 values (@address)
go

use DB2
go

insert into Address
 values (@address)
go
```

I got the following error:

> Must declare the scalar variable '@address'

At this point, I'm totally confused because I've declared the variable `@address` before executing the `insert` statement. Is it because I'm traversing different database?

As of now, I've just put the actual value in the `insert` statement just for the sake of completing the task, though I wondered what caused the error.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

the variable @address only lives in the batch that its defined in, batches are delimited by the the go statement, where it goes out of scope.

try this:

```
declare @address varchar(50)
set @address = 'Hope'

insert into DB1.dbo.Address
 values (@address)

insert into DB2.dbo.Address
 values (@address)
go
```

Comment: Ah, ok. The batch scope is terminated by `go` statement. Now, I know! It's a subtle error :S.

Comment: Thank you!  This was driving me nuts.

Answer (score 6):

It's the GO statement.

> all local variable declarations must be grouped in a single batch.
>   This is done by not having a GO command until after the last statement
>   that references the variable.
>   ([from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188037.aspx))

Answer (score 5):

It's because you are using `go` between the statement that declares the variable and the statement that uses it.

The `go` command is not an SQL command, it's a separator between sessions in Management Studio. Just remove all the `go` commands in your query, and you can use the variable all the way.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue...
So I run all these lines togehter and it worked.
Do try to run all the lines together.

Comment: Hey there! Can you provide a clear answer for the OP to follow on through (such as a SQL query)? This action would improve the quality the answer to the question.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33456868)