# Error when using Parameters in ADODB

Tags: sql-server, vba

```
Dim strSQL As String

strSQL = "INSERT INTO [" & AccountCode & "].[Orders] ( OrderID,OrderDate,BarUTC,OrderUTC,Exchange,Symbol,OrderSignedAmount,OrderPrice,Type,TargetPosition,AccountIdent,Status)" _
          & " VALUES ( @OrderID,@OrderDate,@BarUTC,@OrderUTC,@Exchange,@Symbol,@OrderSignedAmount,@OrderPrice,@Type,@TargetPosition,@AccountIdent,@Status)"

Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command
Set cmd.ActiveConnection = objMyConn

cmd.CommandText = strSQL
cmd.CommandType = adCmdText
cmd.NamedParameters = True
SeqNum = SeqNum + 1
AccountIdent = AccountCode + ":" + ModelCode
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@OrderID", adInteger, adParamInput, -1, SeqNum)
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@OrderDate", adDate, adParamInput, 0, Date)
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@BarUTC", adDBTimeStamp, adParamInput, 0, Time)
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@OrderUTC", adDBTimeStamp, adParamInput, 0, Time)
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@Exchange", adVarChar, adParamInput, -1, "Future")
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@Symbol", adVarChar, adParamInput, -1, Symbol)
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@OrderSignedAmount", adInteger, adParamInput, , TargetPosition)
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@OrderPrice", adDouble, adParamInput, , -1)
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@Type", adVarChar, adParamInput, -1, "MARKETIOC")
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@TargetPosition", adInteger, adParamInput, , TargetPosition)
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@AccountIdent", adVarChar, adParamInput, -1, AccountIdent)
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@Status", adVarChar, adParamInput, -1, "NEW")

cmd.Execute
```

This gives me a "Must declare the scalar variable error "@OrderID"

Why?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7076801/error-must-declare-the-scalar-variable-for-insert-statements-in-multiple-data may help you

Comment: No, that's a different thing. This is about creating parameters in ADODB

Comment: have you checked with profiler how the insert command that is send to the database lookes like ? Maybe you can find some clue there

Comment: I dont know vb but in c# some idiot at microsoft made it so that when the value you give for a parameter is null then the whole parameter is left out of the command, thus giving exact this error

Answer (score 2):

You can't name your parameters in the SQL command text as you've tried to do.

If you change all of them simply to the "?" placeholder then your code should work, e.g.

```
Dim strSQL As String

strSQL = "INSERT INTO [" & AccountCode & "].[Orders] ( OrderID,OrderDate,BarUTC,OrderUTC,Exchange,Symbol,OrderSignedAmount,OrderPrice,Type,TargetPosition,AccountIdent,Status)" _
          & " VALUES ( ?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"

Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command
Set cmd.ActiveConnection = objMyConn

cmd.CommandText = strSQL
cmd.CommandType = adCmdText
cmd.NamedParameters = True
SeqNum = SeqNum + 1
AccountIdent = AccountCode + ":" + ModelCode
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@OrderID", adInteger, adParamInput, -1, SeqNum)
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@OrderDate", adDate, adParamInput, 0, Date)
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@BarUTC", adDBTimeStamp, adParamInput, 0, Time)
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@OrderUTC", adDBTimeStamp, adParamInput, 0, Time)
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@Exchange", adVarChar, adParamInput, -1, "Future")
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@Symbol", adVarChar, adParamInput, -1, Symbol)
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@OrderSignedAmount", adInteger, adParamInput, , TargetPosition)
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@OrderPrice", adDouble, adParamInput, , -1)
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@Type", adVarChar, adParamInput, -1, "MARKETIOC")
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@TargetPosition", adInteger, adParamInput, , TargetPosition)
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@AccountIdent", adVarChar, adParamInput, -1, AccountIdent)
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@Status", adVarChar, adParamInput, -1, "NEW")

cmd.Execute
```

At that point it doesn't matter what you call them when you create the command parameters. Take note that the parameters are passed by ordinal position not by name!

If you want to name the parameters in your SQL code nicely then you should look into creating a stored procedure, although your dynamic schema name would make that tricky.

You could possibly also use `sp_executesql`. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx